# "radio-inline" class not letting multiple group of radio buttons to work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my code i have two rows of inline radio buttons , whenever i click a radio button the two rows are treated as if they are part of the same group

So the each row is unable to have it's own selection here is my code :

```
<p class="text-danger" style="font-size: 20px;margin: 20px 0 10px 0;">Select Your Ad size :</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="ad_size">

        <span class="disp_ad_size disp_active">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" onClick="ad_size(this)" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="size_ad_1" value="size_ad_1" checked><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">4cm x 4cm</span> 
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="disp_ad_size">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" onClick="ad_size(this)" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="size_ad_2" value="size_ad_2"><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">8cm x 6cm</span>  
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="disp_ad_size">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" onClick="ad_size(this)" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="size_ad_3" value="size_ad_3"><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">33cm x 25cm</span>  
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="disp_ad_size">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" onClick="ad_size(this)" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="size_ad_4" value="size_ad_4"><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">33cm x 52cm</span>  
            </label>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="text-danger" style="font-size: 20px;margin: 20px 0 10px 0;">Select Your Ad Position :</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="ad_pos">

        <span class="disp_ad_pos disp_active">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" onClick="ad_pos(this)" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="size_pos_any" value="size_ad_1" checked><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">Any page</span> 
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="disp_ad_pos">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" onClick="ad_pos(this)" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="size_pos_5" value="size_ad_2"><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">3rd page</span>  
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="disp_ad_pos">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" onClick="ad_pos(this)" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="size_pos_3" value="size_ad_3"><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">5th page</span>  
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="disp_ad_pos">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" onClick="ad_pos(this)" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="size_pos_last" value="size_ad_4"><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">Last page</span>  
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="disp_ad_pos" style="margin-right:0px">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" onClick="ad_pos(this)" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="size_pos_front" value="size_ad_4"><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">Front Page</span>  
            </label>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

so i have two divs "ad_size" and "ad_pos" so select a radio button in ad_size changes the radio selection in the other div.

can anybody point out my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the input name should be different; please change all the radio's name in Ad Position, like below codes

```
<span class="disp_ad_pos disp_active">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" onClick="ad_pos(this)" name="inlineRadioOptionsPage" id="size_pos_any" value="size_ad_1" checked><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">Any page</span> 
        </label>
    </span>
    <span class="disp_ad_pos">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" onClick="ad_pos(this)" name="inlineRadioOptionsPage" id="size_pos_5" value="size_ad_2"><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">3rd page</span>  
        </label>
    </span>
    <span class="disp_ad_pos">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" onClick="ad_pos(this)" name="inlineRadioOptionsPage" id="size_pos_3" value="size_ad_3"><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">5th page</span>  
        </label>
    </span>
    <span class="disp_ad_pos">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" onClick="ad_pos(this)" name="inlineRadioOptionsPage" id="size_pos_last" value="size_ad_4"><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">Last page</span>  
        </label>
    </span>
    <span class="disp_ad_pos" style="margin-right:0px">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" onClick="ad_pos(this)" name="inlineRadioOptionsPage" id="size_pos_front" value="size_ad_4"><span style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;">Front Page</span>  
        </label>
    </span>
```

Comment: Oh thanks it worked .... so a radio buttons will be a group if all the inputs have same name... glad that learned something :)

Comment: Yes, You should change all the names of the second grp, the Radios are group by name